# Unable to extract all spans with matching class or id

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, python-requests, lxml

This is probably something stupid. But I am trying to write a simple scraper to grab listing from this website: https://online.ncat.nsw.gov.au/Hearing/HearingList.aspx?LocationCode=2000

Well, actually it will eventually run for each LocationCode but this is an example page.

I want to extract both the `<span>` headings and the `table` data for each date.

The general form of the data is:

```
<span id="lblSubHeader1242017" class="clsGridItem">1:15 PM Wednesday, 12 Apr 2017 at Room 15.6 Level 15, 66 Goulburn st </span>
<hr />
<table id="dg1242017">
    <tr class="clsGridItem">
        <td width="15%">RT 17/11111</td>
        <td width="30%">Name of party</td>
        <td width="55%">Name of party</td>
    </tr>
    ...
 </table>
```

It's rough but I can grab the table data pretty well with code of the form:

```
page = requests.get('https://online.ncat.nsw.gov.au/Hearing/HearingList.aspx?LocationCode=2000')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
events = tree.xpath('//table//td/text()')
```

but when I try to grab the the spans outside the table so I can have location and date information with something like:

```
days = tree.xpath('//span[starts-with(@id,"lbl")]/text()')
```

or

```
days = tree.xpath('//span[@class,"clsGridItem"]/text()')
```

I only get the following two results:

```
days:  ['There are no matters listed in SYDNEY today', 'There are no matters listed in SYDNEY today']
```

These refer to two spans about 2/3 of the way down the page:

```
<span id="lbl1442017" style="font-weight:bold;">SYDNEY: Friday, 14 Apr 2017</span><br /><br /><span id="lblError1442017" class="clsGridItem">There are no matters listed in SYDNEY today</span><br /><br /><br /><span id="lbl1742017" style="font-weight:bold;">SYDNEY: Monday, 17 Apr 2017</span><br /><br /><span id="lblError1742017" class="clsGridItem">There are no matters listed in SYDNEY today</span>
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Why are the other spans being skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get every text content of `<span class="clsGridItem">`:

```
days = tree.xpath('//span[@class="clsGridItem"]//text()')
```

But I have no idea why `//span[@class="clsGridItem"]/text()` is not working as it [should be applicable as well...](https://uploadpie.com/4oV5e7)